# Are there any negative effects to using labels in C to actually label your code for improved readability?

Tags: c, label, readability

I'm a self taught begginner in C and a few weeks ago I had the idea of using labels to label my code blocks, instead of comments. I'm not using them for flow control (I've never used goto) but to differentiate between my comments (I use them for bugs, todo, and "documentation") and my code block "headers" or "titles", to improve readability. For example:

```
int main()
{
   while(true)
   {
      Update:
        DoSomething1();
        DoSomething2();
        DoSomething3();
      Render:
        DrawSomething1();
        DrawSomething2();
   }
}
```

One thing to note is that if there's a declaration after the label the code won't compile, but you can add a ; after the label or use braces where appropiate (being mindful of scope etc)

```
Initialization:;
    int width, height;

DoStuff:
{
   width = 640;
   height = 480;
}
```

I also use it for things like:

```
Player1: entities[0] = PlayerCreate(1);
Player2: entities[1] = PlayerCreate(2);
```

Are there any negative effects to doing this? Undefined behavior or something I should be aware of?

Comment: Labels aren't comments. If you want to document your code, use comments. Labels are for use with `goto`, which you should generally avoid unless you have a really good reason to. If you have a need to differentiate between sections of your code, comments are exactly the tool to use.

Comment: Other than never getting through a code review, nope.

Comment: If it is just for yourself then feel free to do whatever you think makes things more readable. But bear in mind that code in the real world has to be read by many people. Doing non-standard things like using(/abusing) labels as comments is unlikely to win many likes from other people that need to read the code. "readability" is subjective but comments are almost universally accepted as the way to inline document code.

Comment: Let's get rid of those pesky `if()` conditionals, too. `while( x == 5 ) { y = 27; break; }` C offers two flavours of comments: `/* comment */` and `// comment`... Conventions aid the readability of code. Unconventional code is **less** readable.

Comment: You probably get warnings from the compiler about unused labels.  I use options to ensure that warnings cause the compilation to fail.  Such code is a non-starter as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 2):

The top level comments are quite good at describing why using labels are a bad idea.

But, I'd like to add *another* reason:

1. They are *not* descriptive enough!
2. The labels are actually incomplete/bad comments!

Good comments should show *intent*. That is, the code shows the *how*. The comments explain the *what* and/or the *why*.

That is, if we do:

```
FILE *fin = fopen("data.txt","r");
```

*What* file are we opening? And, *why* are we opening it?

Here's a better attempt:

```
// open the customer file [so we can read it] and be able to validate the name
// and account number of the proposed transaction(s)
FILE *fin = fopen("data.txt","r");
```

---

In the first block, you have:

```
while (!MustClose())
```

Must close *what* and *why*?

Also, you have `Update:` and `Render:`

Again, *what* are you updating and *why*? *What* are you rendering and *why*?

---

In the second block in you have:

```
Initialization:;
    int width, height;
```

You are *not* initializing here. You are defining. And, `width` and `height` are the dimensions of *what*? A drawing pad, a window, a surface, the main window, a subwindow?

You would be better off with (e.g.):

```
// dimensions of main window (in pixels)
int width, height;
```

---

In the third block you have:

```
Player1: entities[0] = PlayerCreate(1);
Player2: entities[1] = PlayerCreate(2);
```

Here `Player1:` is redundant extra cruft. It's redundant to `PlayerCreate(1)`

It's like doing:

```
x = 5;  // set the value of x to 5
```

And, there is *nothing* to describe what the block is actually doing. We have to *infer* that we're creating players from `PlayerCreate`.

And, what if `entities` has (e.g.) 1,000 elements? Then, we'd do:

```
// create all players
for (int i = 0;  i < 1000;  ++i)
    entities[i] = PlayerCreate(i + 1);
```

Comment: >Must close what and why?

It's code written for stackoverflow to just show some code. But obviously it's checking if the program/window should close/exit the main loop.

>And, what if entities has (e.g.) 1,000 elements? Then, we'd do:
Thanks for trying to be helpful, I already know this. It's just code for showing some ways I'm using the labels. Also, the player can be a unique entity, while other entities might be created later starting on i = 1.

Sorry for not having typed better examples, I thought it would be taken as an example of the usage of labels.

Comment: Also, I'm making games with C. I think you don't understand the normal structure of a game but really, all I'm doing is have a loop and steps like Update and Render. It's really common. Sorry but your suggestions/answer seem to completely miss the point

Comment: @sodap I have been programming in C for 40+ years and have done games just for fun. If you had looked, I have SO answers re. SDL2. Don't assume for one second that I "do not understand". This was to encourage you to write better comments and clearer code. And, to forego the labels idea. _Must close what and why? But obviously it's checking if the program/window should close/exit the main loop._ So, that's your [missing] comment